# Master and Detail, Angular posting to SQL server issue

Tags: angular

I run into this issue and I got stuck. I am new to Angular. Thank you.  I am using Angular 8 and Sql WebAPI backend with c#.
I have a master and detail situation with 2 classes (ie. masterClass and detailClass[] for example).
I can update or post master record to the backend SQL no issue.  However, I have issues with posting detail records (array of records).

I have to do two steps: 
1. Update master record and it return recordId back to client side.
2. After receiving recordId back then posting details records will take place.

However, all of these processes are async. mode (async. and await).  Is there any sample or example i can look and educate myself? 
My big issue is 'ASYNC RECURSIVE MODE' in this anvironment and how I chain them togeter.

Thank you for any helps.

Comment: please provide some code for understanding

Comment: I can not post my code.  It is really picky (it is good though).  I have to create a github repo so that you can see my codes.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah tell me what's the issue I can try

Comment: It is JSON and GUID issue. It is old bug based upon my research but I don't know how to  code it correctly.

Comment: Sorry it takes a while to learn github... I am slow. Here is the link for the github https://github.com/d052057/Angular9.  I am still playing with this file.  I did comment and uncomment recordId (guid field) to figure out the issue.  Also, I have 3 buttons to test the update. This is VS2019 project.  Two buttons are working with no Record id.  Thanks.